# Trying to acces USB drive from Blander in a Flatpak sandbox

Tags: sandbox, flatpak

I've got Blender 2.79c installed using Flatpak. When trying to load filed from a removable USB drive, I find there's no `/mnt` nor `/media`.

I'm pretty sure this is because of Flatpak's sandboxing.

How is Flatpak supposed to handle this kind of situation? I would expect the flatpak runtime to ask the user for permission and mount whatever resource into the sandboxed fs.

Found no mention of it in the help or anything...

-- nachokb

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so after having this question in draft for 3 hours, I finally posted it. Then immediately found the answer to my own question.

To make this simple, this is what I had to run:

```
flatpak run --filesystem=/media --filesystem=/mnt org.blender.Blender
```

Of course I'll try to update the .desktop file now. But this is basically what's needed: add specific paths to the `filesystem` option or something like that…

Comment: for the record: the .desktop file is in `/var/lib/flatpak/exports/…`